# Capybara doesn't render page in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, capybara

I have a Rails project with Backbone and Capybara for integration tests.

In the test I'm running `save_and_open_page` and it successfully opens the page in browser with valid Javascript.

But when I'm running `puts page.body` (right after `save_and_open_page`) it gives me

```
//skipped

<div id="main">
  Loading...
</div>

</body></html>
```

And then no `have_content` and other selectors work.

How is it possible that it saves and opens valid page but has wrong page body?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default driver for Capybara is Rack::Test. Your page probably requires javacript which means that Capybara's default driver is not rendering everything correctly. Just set `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium`. This way the javascript is run correctly.

See also [link](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/), which explains how to change the driver for only one testcase and not the whole test suite. Note that if you use selenium as the driver the method `save_and_open_page` probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add to `spec_helper.rb` the line

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

and use default browser driver